# htaccess subdomain to a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a problem which I can't fix it. I explain you. I have a website like :

admin.myweb.com

So, I have the CSS, Javascripts in a folder called static and the "admin.myweb.com" needs to take that static files in this way:

static.admin.myweb.com

By now I have my "admin.myweb.com" and it runs well but without CSS,Javascript. So I've created a subdomain called "static.admin.miweb.com".

My problem is that I want the website goes to the folder "/instances/myweb/public/static", when it tries to go to static.admin.myweb.com . I've searched a lot and I tried a lot of httaccess codes but no one worked.

Basically I want to say something like : "when you receive static.admin.myweb.com, go to /instances/myweb/public/static".

I'm getting crazy with htaccess! Does anyone know how to do it? :)

Comment: `I'm getting crazy with htaccess!` and no response to below Answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `/instances/myweb/public` is your website's root directory, place the following rules in your `.htaccess` file there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.admin\.myweb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static/$1 [L]
```